# buttons in interface buider

Tags: xcode, plugins, interface-builder

has anyone an idea if it is possible to create ellipse or polygon buttons in IB?

Answer (score 0):

Directly, not without a library.

You can, however, create an NSView subclass which performs your shape drawing for you. You will need to implement the mouse events to perform clicks correctly. Drop an NSView on your window, set its class in the inspector to your custom-drawn NSView subclass, and you're set. Check out [this tutorial](http://katidev.com/blog/2008/03/07/how-to-create-a-custom-control-with-nsview/).

You could also create a custom control, derived from NSControl. Check out [this documentation.](http://developer.apple.com/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ControlCell/Tasks/SubclassingNSControl.html)

Comment: sorry, but i have another question: can i use this also for iphone-apps?

Comment: In iPhone apps, I *believe* you will be using a UIView instead of an NSView. I just started working those myself, so I'm probably not the best guy to answer it just yet. :)